# How do I automate a web proxy in .NET for unit tests (including set up and tear down)?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, proxy, automation, browser-automation

Following Jonathan Holland's suggestion in his comment for my previous question: [Is there any way in .NET to programmatically listen to HTTP traffic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137360/is-there-any-way-in-net-to-programmatically-listen-to-http-traffic) I've made a separate (but not exactly a duplicate) question for what I *really* want to know:

**How do I automate a web proxy in .NET for unit tests** (including set up and tear down) for spying on HTTP traffic that comes from the browser (particularly images, scripts, and XmlHttpRequests on the requested page)?

I prefer to have zero set-up (so no Fiddler installed on Windows) where everything can be unpacked from an assembly, deployed, and then removed without a trace, so to speak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebAii 2.0 has a built-in HTTP proxy:

http://www.artoftest.com/community/blogs/09-03-25/WebAii_2_0_Beta_Released.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Roll your own pass-through proxy, then have your test harness issue configuration commands on the admin port of the proxy. The proxy will dutifully route any normal connection to the specified ip:port, with minimal "setup."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take control of a browser-like request and look at requests and headers from a stimulated web browser to your localhost, you can use [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.80).aspx)

If you want a .NET solution, where you use complete proxy detection, then have a look at this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300743.aspx. It explains how to integrate with a proxy like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/)

Before using any of these solutions, I strongly recommend that you review your unit tests and what you're trying to accomplish. A full proxy solution is often times out of the scope of unit tests and you may want to scale your tests down a bit.

However, if you are writing integration tests, then these solutions should serve you well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for, but here is an example of ASP.NET unit testing using selenium.
http://www.stevetrefethen.com/blog/AutomatedTestingOfASPNETWebApplicationsUsingSelenium.aspx

Comment: I already have a browser automation framework (WebAii) but it doesn't capture outgoing HTTP traffic.