# Accessing Response Packet from within C# code, using an existing instance of Web Browser

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, user-interface

I am writing C# Coded UI Tests in Visual Studio 2010. To enhance the testing, I need to access all the responses coming back from the server. For instance, I am testing the Add New Member use case, if user’s attempt to add a new member fails, and the UI doesn’t show neither the success or failure massage, I want to be able to get more detail from the http response and show the appropriate respond to the tester.
My code first open an instance of 
SHDocVw.ShellWindows allBrowsers = new SHDocVw.ShellWindows();
                if (allBrowsers.Count > 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Number active browsers = " + allBrowsers.Count + "." + " Please close all windows and try again...");
                    throw new Exception("Multiple IE Instances not allow ");
                }

```
            p = Process.Start("iexplore.exe", "http://bing/");
            BrowserWindow win = new BrowserWindow();


            current.SearchProperties[BrowserWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = "Bing";
           if (p == null) throw new Exception("Could not launch IE");
```

Now, I need to somehow capture all the responses that server sends back to requests going out from the instance of win object?

I am not sure if there is any way to do with HttpContext or such.

Answer (score 0):

To track responses from web server you need to setup your HTTP proxy that you can control from the tests. See [How do I automate a web proxy in .NET for unit tests (including set up and tear down)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137425/how-do-i-automate-a-web-proxy-in-net-for-unit-tests-including-set-up-and-tear-d) , search for something like "fiddler automation unit test" for more articles.

Comment: Thank you Alexei, I have looked into this approch by using GlobalProxySelection with no luck, it would be nice to see a sample code.